# conditional (if statments) on a pointer to a string

Tags: c

Hi i used strtok to split a line I read in from a file using fgets. I was wonder how would I be able to to use a if statement to check each partition of the line.

a line from the file would be something like

1 FirstName-LastName

```
char *stuff;
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), myfile)){
    stuff = strtok(buffer, " ");// this should give me 1
    if( ...... ) // what would be the correct way of saying if stuff == "1"
```

Comment: `if (strncmp(buffer, <string>, stuff - buffer) == 0)`

Comment: Try `strcmp`. I also recommend reading some kind of book on C. They say K&R is good.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is really only useful for comparing integer values.  Use something like `strcmp()`, or `strstr()` to do string compares.

***Something like this.***  (See comments embedded for some explanation...  )

```
char *stuff;
char keep[260];// or some reasonable size to do your comparison.  
               //its best not to use your token to do anything except store the token :)
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), myfile))
{
    stuff = strtok(buffer, " ");// this should give me 1
    while(stuff) // as long as stuff not NULL
    {
        strcpy(keep, stuff);//
        if(strcmp(keep, "1") == 0)  //strtok returns only (char *) and output of strcmp is 0 for equal
        {
            //do something here!
        }
        //get next token
        stuff = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```